# How do I build the vtkLocal example with shared libraries on?

Tags: tcl, swig, vtk

I'm new to VTK and CMake. I have a C++ project that extends some VTK classes, and I'd like to wrap the classes in SWIG in the same manner that VTK does and call them from Tcl.

I'm trying to figure out how use the VTK SWIG wrapping by following the example in Examples/Build/vtkLocal example. I want to access the library as a shared object library and load it with Tcl. if I build vtkLocal with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS on, however, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lTCL
```

Any idea how to resolve this dependency?

I'm using VTK 6.0.

Comment: `TCL` in _upper_ case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you also configured cMake with VTK_WRAP_TCL, Module_vtkRenderingTk and VTK_Group_Tk on?
In my case, I'm using VTK with Python and Tcl bindings, and by doing that, everything works fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @UriAgassi I don't agree... the answer provided suggest a course of action, setting 3 cmake properties. It's something that has worked for Mario and that may help OP